# Wireguard-apple build failed with error: ExternalBuildToolExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

Tags: ios, xcode, macos-catalina, building, wireguard

I'm using Go version 1.13, Mac Catalina, and Xcode 11.7 to build.
The Xcode building process cannot be finished because of the following error.

```
Command ExternalBuildToolExecution failed with a nonzero exit code:

>ExternalBuildToolExecution WireGuardGoBridgemacOS (in target 'WireGuardGoBridgemacOS' from project 'WireGuard')
    cd /Users/mycomputer/Documents/wireguard-apple-master/WireGuard/../wireguard-go-bridge
    export ACTION=
    export ALTERNATE_GROUP=staff
    export ALTERNATE_MODE=u+w,go-w,a+rX
    export ALTERNATE_OWNER=decycle
    export ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES=YES
    export ALWAYS_SEARCH_USER_PATHS=NO
    export APPLE_INTERNAL_DEVELOPER_DIR=/AppleInternal/Developer
    export APPLE_INTERNAL_DIR=/AppleInternal
    export APPLE_INTERNAL_DOCUMENTATION_DIR=/AppleInternal/Documentation
    export APPLE_INTERNAL_LIBRARY_DIR=/AppleInternal/Library
    export APPLE_INTERNAL_TOOLS=/AppleInternal/Developer/Tools
    export APPLICATION_EXTENSION_API_ONLY=NO
    export APPLY_RULES_IN_COPY_FILES=NO
    export APPLY_RULES_IN_COPY_HEADERS=NO
    export APP_ID_IOS=com.27net.vpnapp
    export APP_ID_MACOS=com.27net.vpnapp
    export ARCHS=x86_64
    export ARCHS_STANDARD=x86_64
    export ARCHS_STANDARD_32_64_BIT="x86_64 i386"
    export ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT=i386
    export ARCHS_STANDARD_64_BIT=x86_64
    export ARCHS_STANDARD_INCLUDING_64_BIT=x86_64
    export AVAILABLE_PLATFORMS="appletvos appletvsimulator iphoneos iphonesimulator macosx watchos watchsimulator"
    export BITCODE_GENERATION_MODE=marker
    export BUILD_ACTIVE_RESOURCES_ONLY=NO
    export BUILD_COMPONENTS="headers build"
    export BUILD_DIR=/Users/decycle/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WireGuard-crxuyioyijtaqnfyuzfxrswnwmjc/Build/Products
    export BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=NO
    export BUILD_ROOT=/Users/decycle/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WireGuard-crxuyioyijtaqnfyuzfxrswnwmjc/Build/Products
    export BUILD_STYLE=
    export BUILD_VARIANTS=normal
    export BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR=/Users/decycle/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WireGuard-crxuyioyijtaqnfyuzfxrswnwmjc/Build/Products/Debug
    export BUNDLE_CONTENTS_FOLDER_PATH=Contents/
    export BUNDLE_CONTENTS_FOLDER_PATH_deep=Contents/
    export BUNDLE_EXECUTABLE_FOLDER_NAME_deep=MacOS
    export BUNDLE_EXECUTABLE_FOLDER_PATH=Contents/MacOS
    export BUNDLE_FORMAT=deep
    export BUNDLE_FRAMEWORKS_FOLDER_PATH=Contents/Frameworks
    export BUNDLE_PLUGINS_FOLDER_PATH=Contents/PlugIns
    export BUNDLE_PRIVATE_HEADERS_FOLDER_PATH=Contents/PrivateHeaders
    export BUNDLE_PUBLIC_HEADERS_FOLDER_PATH=Contents/Headers
    export CACHE_ROOT=/var/folders/zb/7qpl989j2y7bj0tj_22jy20h0000gn/C/com.apple.DeveloperTools/11.7-11E801a/Xcode
    export CLANG_ANALYZER_NONNULL=YES
    export CLANG_ANALYZER_NUMBER_OBJECT_CONVERSION=YES_AGGRESSIVE
    export CLANG_CXX_LANGUAGE_STANDARD=gnu++14
    export CLANG_CXX_LIBRARY=libc++
    export CLANG_ENABLE_MODULES=YES
    export CLANG_ENABLE_OBJC_ARC=YES
    export CLANG_ENABLE_OBJC_WEAK=YES
    export CLANG_MODULES_BUILD_SESSION_FILE=/Users/decycle/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex/Session.modulevalidation
    export CLANG_WARN_BLOCK_CAPTURE_AUTORELEASING=YES
    export CLANG_WARN_BOOL_CONVERSION=YES
    export CLANG_WARN_COMMA=YES
    export CLANG_WARN_CONSTANT_CONVERSION=YES
    export CLANG_WARN_DEPRECATED_OBJC_IMPLEMENTATIONS=YES
    export CLANG_WARN_DIRECT_OBJC_ISA_USAGE=YES_ERROR
    export CLANG_WARN_DOCUMENTATION_COMMENTS=YES
    export CLANG_WARN_EMPTY_BODY=YES
    export CLANG_WARN_ENUM_CONVERSION=YES
    export CLANG_WARN_INFINITE_RECURSION=YES
    export CLANG_WARN_INT_CONVERSION=YES
    export CLANG_WARN_NON_LITERAL_NULL_CONVERSION=YES
    export CLANG_WARN_OBJC_IMPLICIT_RETAIN_SELF=YES
    export CLANG_WARN_OBJC_LITERAL_CONVERSION=YES
    export CLANG_WARN_OBJC_ROOT_CLASS=YES_ERROR
    export CLANG_WARN_RANGE_LOOP_ANALYSIS=YES
    export CLANG_WARN_STRICT_PROTOTYPES=YES
    export CLANG_WARN_SUSPICIOUS_MOVE=YES
    export CLANG_WARN_UNGUARDED_AVAILABILITY=YES_AGGRESSIVE
    export CLANG_WARN_UNREACHABLE_CODE=YES_AGGRESSIVE
    export CLANG_WARN__DUPLICATE_METHOD_MATCH=YES
    export CLASS_FILE_DIR=/Users/decycle/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WireGuard-crxuyioyijtaqnfyuzfxrswnwmjc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/WireGuard.build/Debug/WireGuardGoBridgemacOS.build/JavaClasses
    export CLONE_HEADERS=NO
    export CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED=YES
    export CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="Apple Development"
    export CODE_SIGN_INJECT_BASE_ENTITLEMENTS=YES
    export CODE_SIGN_STYLE=Automatic
    export COLOR_DIAGNOSTICS=NO
    export COMPILER_INDEX_STORE_ENABLE=Default
    export COMPRESS_PNG_FILES=NO
    export CONFIGURATION=Debug
    export CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Users/decycle/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WireGuard-crxuyioyijtaqnfyuzfxrswnwmjc/Build/Products/Debug
    export CONFIGURATION_TEMP_DIR=/Users/decycle/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WireGuard-crxuyioyijtaqnfyuzfxrswnwmjc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/WireGuard.build/Debug
    export COPYING_PRESERVES_HFS_DATA=NO
    export COPY_HEADERS_RUN_UNIFDEF=NO
    export COPY_PHASE_STRIP=NO
    export CREATE_INFOPLIST_SECTION_IN_BINARY=NO
    export DEAD_CODE_STRIPPING=NO
    export DEBUGGING_SYMBOLS=YES
    export DEBUG_INFORMATION_FORMAT=dwarf
    export DEFAULT_COMPILER=com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0
    export DEFAULT_DEXT_INSTALL_PATH=/System/Library/DriverExtensions
    export DEFAULT_KEXT_INSTALL_PATH=/System/Library/Extensions
    export DEFINES_MODULE=NO
    export DEPLOYMENT_LOCATION=NO
    export DEPLOYMENT_POSTPROCESSING=NO
    export DEPLOYMENT_TARGET_CLANG_ENV_NAME=MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET
    export DEPLOYMENT_TARGET_CLANG_FLAG_NAME=mmacosx-version-min
    export DEPLOYMENT_TARGET_LD_ENV_NAME=MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET
    export DEPLOYMENT_TARGET_LD_FLAG_NAME=macosx_version_min
    export DEPLOYMENT_TARGET_SETTING_NAME=MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET
    export DERIVED_FILES_DIR=
    export DERIVED_FILE_DIR=/Users/decycle/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WireGuard-crxuyioyijtaqnfyuzfxrswnwmjc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/WireGuard.build/Debug/WireGuardGoBridgemacOS.build/DerivedSources
    export DERIVED_SOURCES_DIR=/Users/decycle/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WireGuard-crxuyioyijtaqnfyuzfxrswnwmjc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/WireGuard.build/Debug/WireGuardGoBridgemacOS.build/DerivedSources
    export DEVELOPER_APPLICATIONS_DIR=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications
    export DEVELOPER_BIN_DIR=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin
    export DEVELOPER_DIR=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    export DEVELOPER_FRAMEWORKS_DIR=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks
    export DEVELOPER_FRAMEWORKS_DIR_QUOTED=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks
    export DEVELOPER_LIBRARY_DIR=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library
    export DEVELOPER_SDK_DIR=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs
    export DEVELOPER_TOOLS_DIR=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Tools
    export DEVELOPER_USR_DIR=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr
    export DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE=en
    export DEVELOPMENT_TEAM=88SM32JH3T
    export DONT_GENERATE_INFOPLIST_FILE=NO
    export DO_HEADER_SCANNING_IN_JAM=NO
    export DSTROOT=/tmp/WireGuard.dst
    export DT_TOOLCHAIN_DIR=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain
    export DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME=.dSYM
    export DWARF_DSYM_FILE_SHOULD_ACCOMPANY_PRODUCT=NO
    export DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH=/Users/decycle/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WireGuard-crxuyioyijtaqnfyuzfxrswnwmjc/Build/Products/Debug
    export EMBEDDED_CONTENT_CONTAINS_SWIFT=NO
    export EMBEDDED_PROFILE_NAME=embedded.provisionprofile
    export EMBED_ASSET_PACKS_IN_PRODUCT_BUNDLE=NO
    export ENABLE_BITCODE=NO
    export ENABLE_DEFAULT_HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS=YES
    export ENABLE_HARDENED_RUNTIME=YES
    export ENABLE_HEADER_DEPENDENCIES=YES
    export ENABLE_ON_DEMAND_RESOURCES=NO
    export ENABLE_PREVIEWS=NO
    export ENABLE_STRICT_OBJC_MSGSEND=YES
    export ENABLE_TESTABILITY=YES
    export ENABLE_TESTING_SEARCH_PATHS=NO
    export EXCLUDED_INSTALLSRC_SUBDIRECTORY_PATTERNS=".DS_Store .svn .git .hg CVS"
    export EXCLUDED_RECURSIVE_SEARCH_PATH_SUBDIRECTORIES="*.nib *.lproj *.framework *.gch *.xcode* *.xcassets (*) .DS_Store CVS .svn .git .hg *.pbproj *.pbxproj"
    export FILE_LIST=/Users/decycle/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WireGuard-crxuyioyijtaqnfyuzfxrswnwmjc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/WireGuard.build/Debug/WireGuardGoBridgemacOS.build/Objects/LinkFileList
    export FRAMEWORK_VERSION=A
    export GCC3_VERSION=3.3
    export GCC_C_LANGUAGE_STANDARD=gnu11
    export GCC_NO_COMMON_BLOCKS=YES
    export GCC_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL=2
    export GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS="DEBUG=1 "
    export GCC_VERSION=com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0
    export GCC_WARN_64_TO_32_BIT_CONVERSION=YES
    export GCC_WARN_ABOUT_RETURN_TYPE=YES_ERROR
    export GCC_WARN_UNDECLARED_SELECTOR=YES
    export GCC_WARN_UNINITIALIZED_AUTOS=YES_AGGRESSIVE
    export GCC_WARN_UNUSED_FUNCTION=YES
    export GCC_WARN_UNUSED_LABEL=YES
    export GCC_WARN_UNUSED_VARIABLE=YES
    export GENERATE_MASTER_OBJECT_FILE=NO
    export GENERATE_PKGINFO_FILE=NO
    export GENERATE_PROFILING_CODE=NO
    export GENERATE_TEXT_BASED_STUBS=NO
    export GID=20
    export GROUP=staff
    export HEADERMAP_INCLUDES_FLAT_ENTRIES_FOR_TARGET_BEING_BUILT=YES
    export HEADERMAP_INCLUDES_FRAMEWORK_ENTRIES_FOR_ALL_PRODUCT_TYPES=YES
    export HEADERMAP_INCLUDES_NONPUBLIC_NONPRIVATE_HEADERS=YES
    export HEADERMAP_INCLUDES_PROJECT_HEADERS=YES
    export HEADERMAP_USES_FRAMEWORK_PREFIX_ENTRIES=YES
    export HEADERMAP_USES_VFS=NO
    export HIDE_BITCODE_SYMBOLS=YES
    export HOME=/Users/decycle
    export INFOPLIST_EXPAND_BUILD_SETTINGS=YES
    export INFOPLIST_OUTPUT_FORMAT=same-as-input
    export INFOPLIST_PREPROCESS=NO
    export INLINE_PRIVATE_FRAMEWORKS=NO
    export INSTALLHDRS_COPY_PHASE=NO
    export INSTALLHDRS_SCRIPT_PHASE=NO
    export INSTALL_DIR=/tmp/WireGuard.dst
    export INSTALL_GROUP=staff
    export INSTALL_MODE_FLAG=u+w,go-w,a+rX
    export INSTALL_OWNER=decycle
    export INSTALL_ROOT=/tmp/WireGuard.dst
    export JAVA_APP_STUB=/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Resources/MacOS/JavaApplicationStub
    export JAVA_ARCHIVE_CLASSES=YES
    export JAVA_ARCHIVE_TYPE=JAR
    export JAVA_COMPILER=/usr/bin/javac
    export JAVA_FRAMEWORK_RESOURCES_DIRS=Resources
    export JAVA_JAR_FLAGS=cv
    export JAVA_SOURCE_SUBDIR=.
    export JAVA_USE_DEPENDENCIES=YES
    export JAVA_ZIP_FLAGS=-urg
    export KEEP_PRIVATE_EXTERNS=NO
    export LD_DEPENDENCY_INFO_FILE=//WireGuardGoBridgemacOS_dependency_info.dat
    export LD_GENERATE_MAP_FILE=NO
    export LD_MAP_FILE_PATH=/Users/decycle/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WireGuard-crxuyioyijtaqnfyuzfxrswnwmjc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/WireGuard.build/Debug/WireGuardGoBridgemacOS.build/WireGuardGoBridgemacOS-LinkMap--.txt
    export LD_NO_PIE=NO
    export LD_QUOTE_LINKER_ARGUMENTS_FOR_COMPILER_DRIVER=YES
    export LEGACY_DEVELOPER_DIR=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/Xcode3Core.ideplugin/Contents/SharedSupport/Developer
    export LIBRARY_DEXT_INSTALL_PATH=/Library/DriverExtensions
    export LIBRARY_FLAG_NOSPACE=YES
    export LIBRARY_KEXT_INSTALL_PATH=/Library/Extensions
    export LINKER_DISPLAYS_MANGLED_NAMES=NO
    export LINK_FILE_LIST_normal_x86_64=/Users/decycle/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WireGuard-crxuyioyijtaqnfyuzfxrswnwmjc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/WireGuard.build/Debug/WireGuardGoBridgemacOS.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/WireGuardGoBridgemacOS.LinkFileList
    export LINK_WITH_STANDARD_LIBRARIES=YES
    export LLVM_TARGET_TRIPLE_OS_VERSION=macos10.15
    export LLVM_TARGET_TRIPLE_VENDOR=apple
    export LOCALIZED_STRING_MACRO_NAMES="NSLocalizedString CFCopyLocalizedString"
    export LOCALIZED_STRING_SWIFTUI_SUPPORT=YES
    export LOCAL_ADMIN_APPS_DIR=/Applications/Utilities
    export LOCAL_APPS_DIR=/Applications
    export LOCAL_DEVELOPER_DIR=/Library/Developer
    export LOCAL_LIBRARY_DIR=/Library
    export LOCROOT=/Users/decycle/Documents/wireguard-apple-master/WireGuard
    export LOCSYMROOT=/Users/decycle/Documents/wireguard-apple-master/WireGuard
    export MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.15
    export MAC_OS_X_PRODUCT_BUILD_VERSION=19G73
    export MAC_OS_X_VERSION_ACTUAL=101506
    export MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MAJOR=101500
    export MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MINOR=1506
    export METAL_LIBRARY_FILE_BASE=default
    export METAL_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIR=/Users/decycle/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WireGuard-crxuyioyijtaqnfyuzfxrswnwmjc/Build/Products/Debug/
    export MODULE_CACHE_DIR=/Users/decycle/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex
    export MTL_ENABLE_DEBUG_INFO=YES
    export MTL_FAST_MATH=YES
    export NATIVE_ARCH=x86_64
    export NATIVE_ARCH_32_BIT=i386
    export NATIVE_ARCH_64_BIT=x86_64
    export NATIVE_ARCH_ACTUAL=x86_64
    export OBJECT_FILE_DIR=/Users/decycle/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WireGuard-crxuyioyijtaqnfyuzfxrswnwmjc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/WireGuard.build/Debug/WireGuardGoBridgemacOS.build/Objects
    export OBJROOT=/Users/decycle/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WireGuard-crxuyioyijtaqnfyuzfxrswnwmjc/Build/Intermediates.noindex
    export ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=YES
    export OS=MACOS
    export PATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/local/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/libexec:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/usr/local/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/usr/local/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
    export PATH_PREFIXES_EXCLUDED_FROM_HEADER_DEPENDENCIES="/usr/include /usr/local/include /System/Library/Frameworks /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Headers /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/SDKs /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms"
    export PER_ARCH_OBJECT_FILE_DIR=/
    export PLATFORM_DEVELOPER_APPLICATIONS_DIR=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications
    export PLATFORM_DEVELOPER_BIN_DIR=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin
    export PLATFORM_DEVELOPER_LIBRARY_DIR=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library
    export PLATFORM_DEVELOPER_SDK_DIR=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs
    export PLATFORM_DEVELOPER_TOOLS_DIR=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Tools
    export PLATFORM_DEVELOPER_USR_DIR=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr
    export PLATFORM_DIR=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform
    export PLATFORM_DISPLAY_NAME=macOS
    export PLATFORM_FAMILY_NAME=macOS
    export PLATFORM_NAME=macosx
    export PLATFORM_PREFERRED_ARCH=x86_64
    export PLATFORM_PRODUCT_BUILD_VERSION=11E801a
    export PLIST_FILE_OUTPUT_FORMAT=same-as-input
    export PRECOMPS_INCLUDE_HEADERS_FROM_BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR=YES
    export PRECOMP_DESTINATION_DIR=/Users/decycle/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WireGuard-crxuyioyijtaqnfyuzfxrswnwmjc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/WireGuard.build/Debug/WireGuardGoBridgemacOS.build/PrefixHeaders
    export PRESERVE_DEAD_CODE_INITS_AND_TERMS=NO
    export PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME=WireGuardGoBridgemacOS
    export PRODUCT_NAME=WireGuardGoBridgemacOS
    export PROFILING_CODE=NO
    export PROJECT=WireGuard
    export PROJECT_DERIVED_FILE_DIR=/Users/decycle/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WireGuard-crxuyioyijtaqnfyuzfxrswnwmjc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/WireGuard.build/DerivedSources
    export PROJECT_DIR=/Users/decycle/Documents/wireguard-apple-master/WireGuard
    export PROJECT_FILE_PATH=/Users/decycle/Documents/wireguard-apple-master/WireGuard/WireGuard.xcodeproj
    export PROJECT_NAME=WireGuard
    export PROJECT_TEMP_DIR=/Users/decycle/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WireGuard-crxuyioyijtaqnfyuzfxrswnwmjc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/WireGuard.build
    export PROJECT_TEMP_ROOT=/Users/decycle/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WireGuard-crxuyioyijtaqnfyuzfxrswnwmjc/Build/Intermediates.noindex
    export REMOVE_CVS_FROM_RESOURCES=YES
    export REMOVE_GIT_FROM_RESOURCES=YES
    export REMOVE_HEADERS_FROM_EMBEDDED_BUNDLES=YES
    export REMOVE_HG_FROM_RESOURCES=YES
    export REMOVE_SVN_FROM_RESOURCES=YES
    export SCAN_ALL_SOURCE_FILES_FOR_INCLUDES=NO
    export SDKROOT=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk
    export SEPARATE_STRIP=NO
    export SEPARATE_SYMBOL_EDIT=NO
    export SHARED_DERIVED_FILE_DIR=/Users/decycle/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WireGuard-crxuyioyijtaqnfyuzfxrswnwmjc/Build/Products/Debug/DerivedSources
    export SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/Users/decycle/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WireGuard-crxuyioyijtaqnfyuzfxrswnwmjc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PrecompiledHeaders
    export SKIP_INSTALL=YES
    export SOURCE_ROOT=/Users/decycle/Documents/wireguard-apple-master/WireGuard
    export SRCROOT=/Users/decycle/Documents/wireguard-apple-master/WireGuard
    export STRINGS_FILE_OUTPUT_ENCODING=UTF-16
    export STRIP_BITCODE_FROM_COPIED_FILES=NO
    export STRIP_INSTALLED_PRODUCT=YES
    export STRIP_PNG_TEXT=NO
    export STRIP_STYLE=all
    export STRIP_SWIFT_SYMBOLS=YES
    export SUPPORTED_PLATFORMS=macosx
    export SUPPORTS_TEXT_BASED_API=NO
    export SWIFT_ACTIVE_COMPILATION_CONDITIONS=DEBUG
    export SWIFT_OBJC_BRIDGING_HEADER=WireGuard/WireGuard-Bridging-Header.h
    export SWIFT_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL=-Onone
    export SWIFT_PLATFORM_TARGET_PREFIX=macos
    export SWIFT_RESPONSE_FILE_PATH_normal_x86_64=/Users/decycle/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WireGuard-crxuyioyijtaqnfyuzfxrswnwmjc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/WireGuard.build/Debug/WireGuardGoBridgemacOS.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/WireGuardGoBridgemacOS.SwiftFileList
    export SWIFT_VERSION=4.2
    export SYMROOT=/Users/decycle/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WireGuard-crxuyioyijtaqnfyuzfxrswnwmjc/Build/Products
    export SYSTEM_ADMIN_APPS_DIR=/Applications/Utilities
    export SYSTEM_APPS_DIR=/Applications
    export SYSTEM_CORE_SERVICES_DIR=/System/Library/CoreServices
    export SYSTEM_DEMOS_DIR=/Applications/Extras
    export SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_APPS_DIR=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications
    export SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_BIN_DIR=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin
    export SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_DEMOS_DIR="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Utilities/Built Examples"
    export SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_DIR=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    export SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_DOC_DIR="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/ADC Reference Library"
    export SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_GRAPHICS_TOOLS_DIR="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Graphics Tools"
    export SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_JAVA_TOOLS_DIR="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Java Tools"
    export SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_PERFORMANCE_TOOLS_DIR="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Performance Tools"
    export SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_RELEASENOTES_DIR="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/ADC Reference Library/releasenotes"
    export SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_TOOLS=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Tools
    export SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_TOOLS_DOC_DIR="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/ADC Reference Library/documentation/DeveloperTools"
    export SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_TOOLS_RELEASENOTES_DIR="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/ADC Reference Library/releasenotes/DeveloperTools"
    export SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_USR_DIR=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr
    export SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_UTILITIES_DIR=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Utilities
    export SYSTEM_DEXT_INSTALL_PATH=/System/Library/DriverExtensions
    export SYSTEM_DOCUMENTATION_DIR=/Library/Documentation
    export SYSTEM_KEXT_INSTALL_PATH=/System/Library/Extensions
    export SYSTEM_LIBRARY_DIR=/System/Library
    export TAPI_VERIFY_MODE=ErrorsOnly
    export TARGETED_DEVICE_FAMILY=1,2
    export TARGETNAME=WireGuardGoBridgemacOS
    export TARGET_BUILD_DIR=/Users/decycle/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WireGuard-crxuyioyijtaqnfyuzfxrswnwmjc/Build/Products/Debug
    export TARGET_NAME=WireGuardGoBridgemacOS
    export TARGET_TEMP_DIR=/Users/decycle/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WireGuard-crxuyioyijtaqnfyuzfxrswnwmjc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/WireGuard.build/Debug/WireGuardGoBridgemacOS.build
    export TEMP_DIR=/Users/decycle/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WireGuard-crxuyioyijtaqnfyuzfxrswnwmjc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/WireGuard.build/Debug/WireGuardGoBridgemacOS.build
    export TEMP_FILES_DIR=/Users/decycle/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WireGuard-crxuyioyijtaqnfyuzfxrswnwmjc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/WireGuard.build/Debug/WireGuardGoBridgemacOS.build
    export TEMP_FILE_DIR=/Users/decycle/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WireGuard-crxuyioyijtaqnfyuzfxrswnwmjc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/WireGuard.build/Debug/WireGuardGoBridgemacOS.build
    export TEMP_ROOT=/Users/decycle/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WireGuard-crxuyioyijtaqnfyuzfxrswnwmjc/Build/Intermediates.noindex
    export TOOLCHAIN_DIR=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain
    export TREAT_MISSING_BASELINES_AS_TEST_FAILURES=NO
    export UID=501
    export USER=decycle
    export USER_APPS_DIR=/Users/decycle/Applications
    export USER_LIBRARY_DIR=/Users/decycle/Library
    export USE_HEADERMAP=YES
    export USE_LLVM_TARGET_TRIPLES=YES
    export USE_LLVM_TARGET_TRIPLES_FOR_CLANG=YES
    export USE_LLVM_TARGET_TRIPLES_FOR_LD=YES
    export USE_LLVM_TARGET_TRIPLES_FOR_TAPI=YES
    export VALIDATE_DEVELOPMENT_ASSET_PATHS=YES_ERROR
    export VALIDATE_WORKSPACE=YES_ERROR
    export VALID_ARCHS="i386 x86_64"
    export VERSION_ID=17
    export VERSION_NAME=0.0.20200127
    export WRAP_ASSET_PACKS_IN_SEPARATE_DIRECTORIES=NO
    export XCODE_APP_SUPPORT_DIR=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Xcode
    export XCODE_PRODUCT_BUILD_VERSION=11E801a
    export XCODE_VERSION_ACTUAL=1170
    export XCODE_VERSION_MAJOR=1100
    export XCODE_VERSION_MINOR=1170
    export arch=undefined_arch
    export variant=normal
    /usr/bin/make
[ -n "" ]

make: *** [/Users/decycle/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WireGuard-crxuyioyijtaqnfyuzfxrswnwmjc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/WireGuard.build/Debug/wireguard-go-bridge/goroot/.prepared] Error 1
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

solution which helped me:
in `build settings` click on the `+` and `add user defined setting`, then add `PATH` as key and `${PATH}:your-go-path` as value (in my case `${PATH}:/usr/local/opt/go@1.13/bin`).
found this somewhere on reddit
**UPD**
while updating wireguard dependency had same scenario build failure
updating go to version 1.16 fixed this (so the `PATH` value for me now looks like `${PATH}:/usr/local/opt/go@1.16/bin`)

**UPD 2**
for mac with M1 the `PATH` should look like this:
`${PATH}:/opt/homebrew/opt/go@1.16/bin`

Comment: I have added `PATH` as you suggested but still getting same error.                             
 make: *** [/Users/<name>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<app_name>/Build/Intermediates.noindex/<app_name>.build/Debug-iphoneos/wireguard-go-bridge/goroot/.prepared] Error 1

Comment: @szashik hey did you find out the solution?

Comment: @SHINTOJOSEPH updating go to version 1.16 in combination with adding `PATH` worked for me

Comment: Adding generic `/opt/homebrew/bin` is enough, `go` is there too.

Comment: One more, "click on the + and add user defined setting" it should be done for project, not for target

Comment: I am still getting the same error even after adding in target and project both: ${PATH}:/opt/homebrew/opt/go@1.16/bin

@potato_fog

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
brew link --force go@1.13
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by installing by using 2 steps

- By Installing Homebrew on Mac
  here is a link for installation -> https://phoenixnap.com/kb/install-homebrew-on-mac
- When Homebrew is installed then install swiftlintgo using below command    in terminal

  $ brew install swiftlint go

Answer (score 0):

if you failed any way
may you path is wrong
reinstall go and use "which go" to find the real path to set

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

fixed the issue for me xcode(15.3)

```
brew install swiftlint go
```